# Short method to retrieve NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute searched

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection, globalization

Is there a better (shorter) method to retrieve the NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute of an assembly than using reflection as implemented below?

```
Public Function GetNeutralResourcesLanguage() As String
    Dim assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly
    Dim attributes = assembly.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(System.Resources.NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute), False)
    If attributes.Length <> 1 Then
        Return "en-US"
    End If

    Dim attribute = CType(attributes(0), System.Resources.NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute)
    Return attribute.CultureName
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most (if not all) .Net attributes are only accessible using reflection ([Attributes (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx)) so the method that you're using, AFAIK, is the best and only way.